# NServiceBus - Exception when starting endpoint. Reason: Could not load Raven.Backup.exe

Tags: c#, .net, nservicebus

I'm trying to run one of the sample projects that came with [NServicebus install](http://nservicebus.com/Downloads.aspx)

I've installed Nservice by running RunMeFirst.bat.  Everything looked fine.

Then I opened one of sample projects (PubSub). It compiles and runs but throws an exception:

> Exception when starting endpoint, error has been logged. Reason: Could
>   not load
>   C:\Users\\Downloads\NServiceBus.3.2.0\NServiceBus.3.2.0\samples\PubSub\MyPublisher\bin\Debug\Raven.Backup.exe.
>   Consider using
>   'Configure.With(AllAssemblies.Except("Raven.Backup.exe"))' to tell
>   NServiceBus not to load this file.

Raven.Backup.exe exists in that folder.

Comment: Remove Raven.Backup.exe from the bin folder. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

I've just d/l v3.2.0 and no problems running PubSub.
Did you unblock the zip file, before unzipping it? 
See http://docs.particular.net/platform/ for instructions on how to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Removing Reven.Backup.exe from bin or doing `'Configure.With(AllAssemblies.Except("Raven.Backup.exe"))'` fixes the problem. It would be good to know why that file is there.